# Twitter sign-in user with PHP and curl

Tags: php, curl, twitter, twitter-login

I'm trying to signin the user just with PHP and `curl`, without any external libraries for **Twitter** authentication. I follow [these Twitter instructions](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing). <s>But I can't figure out how to complete step 3.</s>

**1.** Obtaining a request token (done)

**2.** Redirecting the user (done)

**3.** Converting the request token to an access token. (done <s>* problem</s>)

Here is my code:

```
    // API SETTINGS
    $consumerSecret = 'xxx';
    $consumerKey = 'xxx';
    $oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA1';

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_verifier'])) {

        // STEP 1 - TWITTER OBTAINING A REQUEST TOKEN
        $callbackUrl = 'http://localhost/skeletons/webiik/example/login/';
        $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';

        // Data we will send
        $data = [
            'oauth_callback' => $callbackUrl,
            'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
            'oauth_signature_method' => $oauth_signature_method,
            'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
            'oauth_nonce' => $token->generate(3),
            'oauth_version' => '1.0',
        ];

        // Sort data alphabetically, because Twitter requires that
        ksort($data);

        // Generate signature and add it to data array
        $signData = 'POST&' . urlencode($url) . '&' . urlencode(http_build_query($data));
        $secret = '';
        $signKey = urlencode($consumerSecret) . '&' . urlencode($secret);
        $data['oauth_signature'] = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $signData, $signKey, true));

        // Prepare http headers from data
        $httpHeaders = [];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $httpHeaders[] = urlencode($key) . '="' . urlencode($value) . '"';
        }

        // Add OAuth header with all data
        $httpHeaders = 'Authorization: OAuth ' . implode(', ', $httpHeaders);

        // Send post request to Twitter API with http headers and data
        $res = $http->post($url, ['httpHeaders' => [$httpHeaders]], []);

        // If we got some error, show error message and stop
        if (count($res['err']) > 0) {
            echo $res['err'];
            exit;
        }

        // Prepare data for step 2 and 3 from Twitter's response
        parse_str($res['body'], $res);
        $oauth_callback_confirmed = $res['oauth_callback_confirmed'];
        $oauth_request_token = $res['oauth_token'];

        // Store oauth_token_secret into session, we will need it in step 3
        $this->sessions->setToSession('oauth_token_secret', $res['oauth_token_secret']);
        $this->sessions->setToSession('oauth_token', $oauth_request_token);

        // STEP 2 - REDIRECTING THE USER TO TWITTER LOGIN
        header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
        header('Location: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=' . urlencode($oauth_request_token));
    }

    // STEP 3 - CONVERTING THE REQUEST TOKEN TO AN ACCESS TOKEN
    $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token';
    $oauth_token = $_GET['oauth_token'];
    $oauth_verifier = $_GET['oauth_verifier'];

    // Data we will send
    $data = [
        'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
        'oauth_nonce' => $token->generate(3),
        'oauth_signature_method' => $oauth_signature_method,
        'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
        'oauth_token' => $oauth_token,
        'oauth_version' => '1.0',
    ];

    // Sort data alphabetically, because Twitter requires that
    ksort($data);

    // Generate signature and add it to data array
    $signData = 'POST&' . urlencode($url) . '&' . urlencode(http_build_query($data));
    $secret = $this->sessions->getFromSession('oauth_token_secret');
    $signKey = urlencode($consumerSecret) . '&' . urlencode($secret);
    $data['oauth_signature'] = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $signData, $signKey, true));

    // Sort data also with added oauth_signature, just for sure
    ksort($data);

    // Prepare http headers from data
    $httpHeaders = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $httpHeaders[] = urlencode($key) . '="' . urlencode($value) . '"';
    }

    // Add OAuth header with all data
    $httpHeaders = ['Authorization: OAuth ' . implode(', ', $httpHeaders)];
    $httpHeaders[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen('oauth_verifier=' . urlencode($oauth_verifier));
    $httpHeaders[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

    // Add oauth_verifier to POST data
    $postData = ['oauth_verifier' => $oauth_verifier];

    // Send post request to Twitter API with http headers and data
    $res = $http->post($url, ['httpHeaders' => $httpHeaders], $postData);

    // If we got some error, show error message and stop
    if (count($res['err']) > 0) {
        echo $res['err'];
        exit;
    }

    print_r($res);
```

**Edit 1:**
$http is just object that creates standard curl requests. In third step the curl request looks like:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
     CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1,
     CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
     CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
     CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $arrayOfHttpHeaders,
     CURLOPT_POST => 1,
     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postData),
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Process response...
```

**Edit 2:** 
I just updated the code to be more accurate to Twitter's example. Now I really don't know where can be the problem.

**Edit 3:** 
Solution: The code is ok. I had problem with router, which added slash at the end of URL. And I grabbed verifier_token with that slash.

Comment: You say you're using cURL but I don't see any curl_exec commands? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jordan I updated the question. $http is just an object that creates curls requests.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and ensured all of your headers and post variables are indeed correct? Also, check out this twitter api console: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console to manually enter your generated values to see if they work. Other than that, I am not seeing anything glaring in your code.

Comment: @Jordan Yes I did many checks: headers, post data, final curl and so on. Thank you for tip for the console, but this console is great when you are already signed in.